# how to send images encoded in base64 in smack in android

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire, smack

I'm trying to send images encoded in *base64* to Openfire Server using smack.

I'm unable to send the Images encoded in base64 using the **sendFile** method.

Below is the code :

```
public void sendImage(String base64Image, String to) throws SmackInvocationException {

        if (fileTransferManager == null || !isConnected()) {
            throw new SmackInvocationException("server not connected");
        }

        String fullJid = to + "/" + RESOURCE_PART;

        OutgoingFileTransfer transfer = fileTransferManager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(fullJid);

        try {
               transfer.sendFile(base64Image,"encoded image");

        } catch (SmackException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "send file error");
            throw new SmackInvocationException(e);
        }

    }
```

Any help is appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to write the content on the Base64 string into a FileOutputStream before sending as a file?

Comment: I want to send the content as a string rather @Cool Guy CG

Comment: Is there a method to send string texts instead of a file ?

Comment: Sending a string is the same as sending a text message, which is not the purpose of the sendFile method.

Comment: Thanks @ Cool Guy CG. Will try sending it as a message.